# Meteor cordova does not allow CORS

Tags: cordova, meteor, cors

```
(android:http://meteor.local/:0) 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com/sockjs/info?cb=mb48b4056b. 
Origin http://meteor.local is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Meteor does not allow CORS requests in Cordova.

How can I work around this problem?

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3469

Comment: Are you sure you server sends a header with Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* option ?

Comment: Hello DanielN, can you please explain what you mean? Where and how I can check this. Is there some article explaining this?

Answer (score 3):

By default your application has a limited list of servers it can contact. Use this method to extend this list.

you need to set App.accessRule("*"); or App.accessRule("*://myserver.com/*");)

in mobile-config.js file, which is not included in your application and is used only for this configuration.

Comment: @gumkins, can you plz provide more info abt your issues, it works very well for me, btw for more details you can explore http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs.

Comment: Hello Naveen, I tried to send cross-origin requests from frontend. I thought this setting will solve my problem, but it didn't. Now I send requests from backend and there is no same origin issue.

Answer (score 0):

For CORS requests, the server **also** needs to add headers to its response, for simple cases this extra header would be enough:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

The Meteor's `WebApp` package can help with the issue, sample code and detailed explanation can be found here:

http://enable-cors.org/server_meteor.html